# John the Ripper - password without repeating letters

Tags: kali-linux, password, aircrack-ng, john-the-ripper

Note: I'm not going to put output of commands because thread will be very long.

Solutions I have already tried didn't succeeded to make the desired output.
If anybody knows is it possible to get a wordlist of passwords that are 8 characters long (only Uppercase letters, no numbers, no special characters), but without repeating letters in a line, for example:

QWERTYUI →→→ good
QQWERTYU →→→ bad
QQQWERTY →→→ bad
QQQQWERT →→→ bad
QQQQQWER →→→ bad
QQQQQQWE →→→ bad
QQQQQQQW →→→ bad

Is there any options with "John The Ripper" to make output wordlist like above or maybe pipe to aircrack-ng? I've tried `crunch` and didn't manage to do that. If is possible I would like to know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a file with words, and you'd like to delete all words that contain repeated characters, then this will do that for you:

```
$ cat file
HELLO
WORLD

$ sed '/\(.\)\1/d' file
WORLD
```

This could be part of a pipeline:

```
$ generate_words | sed '/\(.\)\1/d' | use_words
```

Where `generate_words` is some program that generates words, one per line, on standard output, and `use_words` is some program that reads words, one per line, from standard input.

The regular expression `\(.\)\1` will match any line of input that contains twe consecutive characters that are the same.  The `d` command of `sed` will delete such lines.

Comment: Is this possible to accomplish without file with words?

Comment: One way would be to generate all permutations of all 8-combinations from `string.ascii_uppercase` in Python.

Comment: Since I haven't used the tools that you mention, I don't know if it's possible to modify the behaviour of them. The pipeline that I included does not use a separate file of words.

Comment: Ah. I see what the actual question is now... You want to _generate_ the words. My bad, I misunderstood the problem.  I'll leave this here in case it help someone else though.

Comment: @Kusalananda this is helpful as well

Answer (score 0):

```
while < /dev/urandom tr -cd 'A-Z' | fold -w8 | sed '/\(.\).*\1/d;q1'; do :; done
```

Here we pick only capital letter chars from `/dev/urandom` file and put it in a `while` loop & keep at it till we see no repeat chars. Note this requires GNU sed.